# htaccess redirect based on IP range

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I'm having a bit of a trouble here.
I 've got wordpress intranet server with two interfaces and two different IP addresses. This server is in private MPLS where is no DNS server. 
Instead of domain name users use IPs.

I would like to rewrite address in htaccess for one of my subnets so it use redirect rule like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.71\.(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|255\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4])))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://10.71.2.246 [R=301,L]
```

This rule does not work.

Remote addr regex should be address range `10.71.0.1` - `10.71.255.254`

I have this several rewrite rules which I think does not work.

Comment: The regex is probably generated with [this tool](http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex) and is working just fine, only a bit over-complicated. However, you don't explain what you are trying to achieve with this. What the user types in the address bar? If it's already an IP, why should it be redirected? How it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my problem is that when I want to access to some media attached to web site from range 10.71.x.x , it redirects me to 10.1.2.xx which is second subnet. This files was uploaded from 10.1.2.xx subbne so it has been hardlinked to 10.1.2.180/xxxxxxx.pdf

So the process is as follows -

1. User accesses Wordpress site at http://10.71.x.y
2. Website is returned but includes media hardlinked to 10.1.x.y. `e.g <a href="http://10.1.x.y/mediafile.pdf">...</a>`
3. User clicks on the link, which doesn't work.

For this issue, a htaccess rewrite will not work. Rewrite is useful for when a user requests one path from the server and you want to direct them to a different path. In your case the client clicks a link they are unable to reach so the request never makes it to the server to be rewritten.

Manually changing the IP from 10.1.x.y to 10.71.x.y in the browser (as in the comment on the previous answer) completely negates the need for the rewrite. (In fact if the rewrite worked you'd probably just get into a redirect loop because every single request would come from a 10.71 address, match the condition and get rewritten)

As I see it there are a couple of options -

1. Make Wordpress use relative URLs everywhere so that all requests go to the same IP address the user originally typed in their browser. Unfortunately Wordpress seems to really like fully qualified URLs for reasons that escape me.
2. Set up DNS or hosts entries at both user sites so that they can enter `http://some.intranet.url` in their browser and have it resolve to the correct IP address. This then means updating Wordpress to use this URL which may also require using a plugin to find and rewrite and old URLs in the database. (Again, Wordpress really likes stuffing full URLs all over the place).
3. Use some sort of filter (I'd be surprised if this doesn't exist as a Wordpress plugin) to scan the Wordpress html after it has been generated and replace any fully qualified links with relative ones.

Option 3 is a bit ugly but probably the easiest option. It just means finding a plugin that can scan the pages for `http://10.a.b.c` and remove it so that a link to `http://10.1.2.3/media/file.pdf` becomes `/media/file.pdf`. (Note: Depending on your setup there may be a bit of tweaking required to make sure it rewrites all the links it needs to but nothing it doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

> Remote addr regex should be address range `10.71.0.1` - `10.71.255.254`

Your regex could be greatly simplified. I would instead look at this as any IP address that starts `10.71`, but excludes `10.71.0.0` and `10.71.255.255` - which would seem to be what you are describing. (?)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.71
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.71\.0\.0$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.71\.255\.255$
RewriteRule ^ http://10.71.2.246%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I've assumed you would want to redirect and maintain the URL-path, rather than redirect all requests to the document root?

This is currently a `302` (temporary) redirect. Change to a `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

However, this does seem a bit strange... `REMOTE_ADDR` is the local IP address of the user connecting to the site (assuming there are no proxy servers involved), but you are redirecting to one of the same IP addresses?

Comment: my problem is that when I want to access to some media attached to web site from range 10.71.x.x , it redirects me to 10.1.2.xx which is second subnet.  This files was uploaded from 10.1.2.xx subbne so it has been hardlinked to 10.1.2.180/xxxxxxx.pdf.

Comment: Sounds like .htaccess won't help you then. If the URL for the file is http://10.1.2.180/... the browser will try (and fail) to connect to that IP to load the media, not ever getting as far as your .htaccess file. You really need the website to use relative URLs, or setup DNS at each user site (or even just hosts file if it's not many users) so they all enter the same hostname to access the site.

Comment: Also regarding simplifying the regex above, I think you could drop the two rules to match `0.0` and `255.255`, and just match `10.71`. I suspect OP just listed that range as that's the "useable" range on the /16, but I doubt those 2 addresses really need to be excluded from the redirect.

Comment: It somehow works , becouse if i edit address of 10.1.2.xx/xxxx.pdf in browser to 10.71.2.xx/xxxx.pdf it shows me correct file ..

Comment: I don't know if this exists, but the other option would be a Wordpress plugin that can do a find/replace on the html output before display. Bit ugly but that would allow you to find any links to `http://10.1.2.xx/somepath` and replace it with `/somepath`